# Split this String into array using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have following String `linear-gradient(124deg, rgb(255, 36, 0), rgb(232, 29, 29), rgb(232, 183, 29), rgb(227, 232, 29), rgb(29, 232, 64), rgb(29, 221, 232), rgb(43, 29, 232), rgb(221, 0, 243), rgb(221, 0, 243))`

I want to split into arrray like

```
[
    "rgb(255, 36, 0)",
    "rgb(232, 29, 29)",
    "rgb(232, 183, 29)",
    "rgb(227, 232, 29)",
    "rgb(29, 232, 64)",
    "rgb(29, 221, 232)",
    "rgb(43, 29, 232)",
    "rgb(221, 0, 243)",
    "rgb(221, 0, 243)"
]
```

Can some one please help how to do this using js/jquery reguar expression 
Thanks.

Comment: Please add what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: Actually I'm poor at regex and i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: You should show what you've tried, so people can help you fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a regular expression for this.

```js
var gradient = 'linear-gradient(124deg, rgb(255, 36, 0), rgb(232, 29, 29), rgb(232, 183, 29), rgb(227, 232, 29), rgb(29, 232, 64), rgb(29, 221, 232), rgb(43, 29, 232), rgb(221, 0, 243), rgb(221, 0, 243))';
var rgbRegex = /rgb\((\d{1,3}), (\d{1,3}), (\d{1,3})\)/g;
var colors = gradient.match(rgbRegex);
console.log(colors);
```

Comment: But what does g at the last stands for ? Thanks

Comment: [Global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global). This is used to find all matches in the string, not just the first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
function parse(text) {
  return text.match(/rgb\(.+?\)/g);
}

console.log(parse('linear-gradient(124deg, rgb(255, 36, 0), rgb(232, 29, 29), rgb(232, 183, 29), rgb(227, 232, 29), rgb(29, 232, 64), rgb(29, 221, 232), rgb(43, 29, 232), rgb(221, 0, 243), rgb(221, 0, 243))'));
```

Comment: just a hint: `rgb\([^\)]+\)` would go faster